# How can I automatically add "Dear sir" to every new Outlook 2007 email?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I usually put the words "Dear sr" at the top of every message I send in Outlook 2007.

I'd like that this was inserted automatically like Outlook does with signatures.

How can I do this?

Comment: What if they are a "madam"?

Comment: Anything wrong with making a longer signature and you just type within the signature for each message?

Comment: @Luke That's a good idea.

Comment: @iglvzx Made an answer

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-a-salutation-to-a-message-HA001175272.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a normal email enter "Dear Sir". Publish to the Personal Forms Library. Name it Male.

Call the form with a macro. http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

```
Sub DisplayMaleForm()
Dim MyFolder
Dim myItem As MailItem
' create new outgoing message based on a form
Set MyFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItem = MyFolder.items.Add("IPM.Note.Male")
myItem.Display
End Sub
```

Create a button. http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm

Repeat with a form named Female that starts "Dear Madam".

Note: There is usually no spellcheck on a signature.

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with creating a long signature? As an example below...

> Dear Sir,

> Sincerely,
>
> Luke
>   Super God of Super User

Comment: The main issue with this is that the cursor won't be placed in the correct place for writing the body of the e-mail.